# Round Display Picture

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-framework-7

Im creating an application which includes the home screen. This will have a biography of the client. Im trying to create a header, which will include the title and a round display image. From the code i used 3 divs, which will hold the wrapper, title and picture. I done the display:flex which will have them in 1 line, and flex:1 to move the image to the right. When doing the radius 50% its squishing the photo . Can you help me out?

Thanks. Heres the code.

```css
.headerOfBio {
  display: flex
}

.displayPic {
  flex: 1 background-image: url("../images/displayPicture.jpg") border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="quote titleBio">
  <div class="headerOfBio">
    <h3>
      MEET THE <span class="diffColor">FOUNDER</span>
    </h3>

    <div class="displayPic">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image]

After adding height and width it becomes like this:

[image]

Comment: you have to specify height & width

Comment: See if you can produce a working example of the issue, a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Embedded screenshots help in demonstrating the issue but you can't debug them or troubleshoot them, it's *always* preferable seeing the code for this reason. At a glance though, it looks like you just need to declare a `flex-basis` for the image in question (this is like a minimum width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a background image to a div, adding a img tag will give a better result.

```css
.headerOfBio {
  display: flex;
}

.displayPic img {
  flex: 1; 
  width:50%;
  border-radius:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="quote titleBio">
  <div class="headerOfBio">
    <h3>
      MEET THE <span class="diffColor">FOUNDER</span>
    </h3>

    <div class="displayPic">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/250/250/nature" /> 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mention width, height for the div holding the image and change border-radius to half of the width/height.

```
.displayPic{
    flex: 1
    background-image: url("../images/displayPicture.jpg")
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
 }
```

Comment: When adding width and height it will become like this. I will upload a photo

Comment: Better if you can create a working demo using stackoverflow snippet or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Why have you used flex:1?

Try this...

```
.headerOfBio {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.displayPic {
  background: url("https://aeutas.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/people-icon.png") no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius : 50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cd3czf30/1/